# Retrieve MSAccess database column description

Tags: c#, database-schema, ms-access-2003

I have an MS Access 2002-2003 database. I'd like to know if there's a way to programmatically retrieve the column descriptions. I can already obtain the column type, name, etc. using

```
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);

DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();

foreach (DataRow myField in schemaTable.Rows)
{
   foreach (DataColumn myProperty in schemaTable.Columns)
   {
      // etc...
   }
}
```

but I don't have access to the "Description" information (which you can view when using "Design View" in MSAccess).

Is there a simple way to get the "Description" information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I retrieve column descriptions from an access database in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936901/how-can-i-retrieve-column-descriptions-from-an-access-database-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
string columnName = "myColumnName"

ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.CatalogClass();
ADODB.Connection conn = new ADODB.Connection();
conn.Open(ConnectionString, null, null, 0);
cat.ActiveConnection = conn;
ADOX.Table mhs = cat.Tables["myTableName"];

columnDescription = mhs.Columns[columnName].Properties["Description"].Value.ToString();

conn.Close();
```

This works great, except I had some trouble finding the right assemblies to add as references.  I had to add a reference to **adodb.dll** (which comes with .Net). I also had to add a reference to **Microsoft ADO Ext. 2.8 for DDL and Security** which is an ActiveX component (found in the COM tab when adding references in Visual Studio).

Code snippets are great, but if you omit reference information, some people get stuck ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using an ADOX catalogue, you can look at the field property Description, in VBA:

```
catDB.ActiveConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & CurrentProject.FullName

Set tbl = catDB.Tables("New")

Set fld = tbl.Columns("Test")
Debug.Print fld.Properties("Description")
```

copy from [How can I retrieve column descriptions from an access database in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936901/how-can-i-retrieve-column-descriptions-from-an-access-database-in-c)

Comment: I realise now that my question is a duplicate, although I'll add my own answer with some additional information. Thanks!